# One Javascript not able to read data generated by ajax script

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I have a situation in which my Jquery Ajax script generates HTML table. And another script is meant to filter the table column by providing a dropdown comprising of unique values in that particular column.

If i have static content in html page the filter script works fine. But is not able to read table content when it is generated via Ajax that is during runtime.

Any idea what could be the reason. I also tried to align script in order.

My Ajax script is here:-

```
$(document).ready(function() {


    $("#getResults").click(function(){ 


             bug = $("#bug").val();
             priority = $("#priority").val();
             component = $("#component").val();
             fixVersion = $("#fixVersion").val();
             dateType = $("#dateType").val();
             fromDate = $("#dp2").val();
             toDate = $("#dp3").val();


            $("#query").empty();

            $("tbody").empty();


            $.post("getRefineSearchResultsPath", {bug:bug,priority:priority,component:component,
                    fixVersion:fixVersion,dateType:dateType,fromDate:fromDate,toDate:toDate },
                    function(data) {

                // setting value for csv report button
                //clear the value attribute for button first
                $("#query_csv").removeAttr("value");

                //setting new value to "value" attribute of the csv button
                $("#query_csv").attr("value", function(){
                    return $(data).find("query").text();
                });

                $("#query").append("<p class='text-success'>Query<legend></legend><small>" +$(data).find("query").text() +"</small></p>");

                var count = 1;

                $(data).find("issue").each(function(){

                    var $issue = $(this);

                    var value = "<tr>";

                    value += "<td>" +count +"</td>";
                    value += "<td>" +$issue.find('issueKey').text() +"</td>";
                    value += "<td>" +$issue.find('type').text() +"</td>";
                    value += "<td><div id='list' class='summary'>" +$issue.find('summary').text() +"</div></td>";
                    value += "<td><div id='list' class='mousescroll'>" +$issue.find('description').text() +"</div></td>";
                    value += "<td>" +$issue.find('priority').text() +"</td>";
                    value += "<td>" +$issue.find('component').text() +"</td>";
                    value += "<td>" +$issue.find('status').text() +"</td>";
                    value += "<td>" +$issue.find('fixVersion').text() +"</td>";
                    value += "<td>" +$issue.find('resolution').text() +"</td>";
                    value += "<td>" +$issue.find('created').text() +"</td>";
                    value += "<td>" +$issue.find('updated').text() +"</td>";
                    value += "<td>" +$issue.find('os').text() +"</td>";
                    value += "<td>" +$issue.find('frequency').text() +"</td>";

                    value += "<td>";

                    var number_of_attachement = $issue.find('attachment').size();

                    if(number_of_attachement > 0){

                        value += "<div id='list' class='attachment'>";
                        value += "<ul class='unstyled'>";

                        $issue.find('attachment').each(function(){

                            var $attachment = $(this);

                            value += "<li>";
                            value += "<a href='#' onclick='document.f1.attachmentName.value='" +$attachment.find('attachmentName').text(); 
                            value += "';document.f1.issueKey.value='"+$attachment.find('attachmentissueKey').text();
                            value += "';document.f1.digest.value='"+$attachment.find('attachmentdigest').text();
                            value += "';document.f1.submit();'>"+$attachment.find('attachmentName').text();
                            value += "</a>";
                            value += "</li>";
                            value += "<br>";
                        });

                        value +="</ul>";
                        value +="</div>";
                    }

                    value += "</td>";
                    value += "</tr>";

                    $("tbody").append(value);

                    count++;


                }); 

            });


        });

});
```

And my script to filter table is here, I got this script from this link http://www.javascripttoolbox.com/lib/table/

My JSP page is here:-

```
<html>
<body>
<table class="table table-bordered table-condensed table-hover example sort01 table-autosort:0 table-autofilter table-autopage:10 table-page-number:t1page table-page-count:t1pages table-filtered-rowcount:t1filtercount table-rowcount:t1allcount">

                    <thead >
                    <tr>
                        <th class="table-sortable:numeric" Style="width:3%;">No.</th>  
                            <th class="table-sortable:default" Style="width:5.5%;">Issue Key <br> 
                            </th>

                            <th>Type</th>
                            <th Style="text-align: center;">Summary</th>
                            <th Style="text-align: center;">Description</th>

                            <th class="table-filterable table-sortable:default" id ="priorityColumn" Style="width:5%">Priority</th>

                            <th class="table-filterable table-sortable:default" >Component</th>
                            <th class="table-filterable table-sortable:default" Style="width:5%">Status</th>
                            <th class="table-filterable table-sortable:default">Fix Version</th>
                            <th class="table-filterable table-sortable:default" Style="width:6%">Resolution</th>
                            <th>Created</th>
                            <th>Updated</th>
                            <th>OS</th>
                            <th>Frequency</th>
                            <th>Attachments</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>

                    <tbody>



                    </tbody>

                    <tfoot>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="table-page:previous" style="cursor:pointer;"><img src="table/icons/previous.gif" alt="Previous"><small>Prev</small></td>
                            <td colspan="13" style="text-align:center;">Page <span id="t1page"></span>&nbsp;of <span id="t1pages"></span></td>
                            <td class="table-page:next" style="cursor:pointer;">Next <img src="table/icons/next.gif" alt="Previous"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr Style="background-color: #dddddd">
                            <td colspan="15"><span id="t1filtercount"></span>&nbsp;of <span id="t1allcount"></span>&nbsp;rows match filter(s)</td>
                        </tr>   
                        <tr class="text-success">
                            <td colspan="15">Total Results : ${count}</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tfoot>
            </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is likely that the filter script reads the intial table data on page load and stores a big object which is then what gets filtered. You AJAX is visibly changing the html but not the data object.

A cursory glance and search of the text in the support documentation didn't reveal any support for AJAX for me. It also doesn't appear to include `destroy` methods so you could reinitialize after the AJAX. The API for the script doesn't appear very robust either.

I would suggest you look for an integrated table system that supports ajax like datatables.js or jQgrid. Both remain in active development and are widely used

Comment: Thanks for your response, I am new to Ajax-jquery infact this is the first project I am working on with this technology. I have another quick question, is my approach to create the html table correct? And also if you look closely in ajax script I have written the attribute for <a> tag, is this correct? Thanks :)

Comment: approach for parsing the xml is right. You can use jQuery instead of `onclick` and write less code as well as keep the javascript removed from the html. jQuery is javascript but in the long run makes coding a lot faster and easier

Comment: Using `$('form').serialize()` instead of lengthy copying of inputs' values into identically named variables will make it so much easier to read and debug.